# Compositum of totally ramified extensions is not totally ramified

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Given $\mathbb{K}$ local non archimedean field, how can I find an example of two totally ramified extensions of $\mathbb{K}$ whose compositum is *not* totally ramified?

I know that every such extension is generated by a uniformizer, but I don't know how to start attacking the problem. Any hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Try extending $\Bbb{Q}_2$ by adjoining two distinct cube roots of two. If you adjoin both of them you also get something that gives an unramified extension.

Comment: Ok, it works! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Well done, Angelo!

Comment: Let $x,y$ be two distinct cube roots of $2$. Then $\mathbb{Q}_2(x)/\mathbb{Q}_2$ is totally ramified. But for $\mathbb{Q}_2(x,y)/\mathbb{Q}_2$, if I am not wrong.  we have ramification index $e=3$, inertia index $f=2$. In particular, it is ramified extension. What do you mean by "something that gives an unramified extension"?

Comment: @DougLiu $\Bbb{Q}_2(x/y)/\Bbb{Q}_2$ is unramified. That's all I meant.

Comment: @DougLiu As per your calculation you saw that $\Bbb{Q}_2(x,y)$ is not **totally** ramified, which is all we need here. There will then automatically be an intermediate extension that is unramified. Also, when a Galois extension is not totally ramified, there will be an intermediate field that is unramified over the base field.